# pouplate another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i have a home page whereby i have an image serving a profile picture and in my view for a shop i want to be able to click the unlock button and the image should replace the current image with the new one using javascript,here is what i have done so far;

**home view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-5 "style="border:4px solid black; padding-right: 100px;">

      <img class ="img-fluid" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/'.$img; ?>" width="250" height="auto">
```

**shop view**

```
<form id="1">
</div>
<div>
<div class="col-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">

                    <div class="service-thumb bg-grey">

                         <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>   

<figure><a href=""> <img class ="img-circle" src="<?=base_url();?>/assets/images/hero1.png" width="250" height="150"></a><figcaption><h4><font color="black">This fearless warrior relies on his bulging muscles to wreck havoc on yor enemies, can be unlocked by achieving 5000 points</font></h4></figcaption></figure><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="signupimg('hero1p.png');" id="btn1" value="unlock">
</div>
</div><br><p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function signupimg(y){
  document.getElementById("signupimage").value = y;
  document.getElementById("signupimage2").value = y;
}
</script>
```

**controller**

```
public function shop()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $this->load->view('shop');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the profile image, you need to add functionality to `click event` on the other image, then you'd want to check if the user has accumulated 5000 points or not(either through `session` or `DB`), if yes then change the `src` of the profile pic.
I've created a working snippet, comments are mentioned wherever deemed necessary. See if it helps you.

```js
document.querySelector('#unlock_pic').addEventListener('click', (event) => { // add click event to other pic
  // console.log(event.target.src)
  // before changing the image, check the condition, if the user has 5000 points, if yes, save it in database, then do this ↓↓
  document.querySelector('#profile_pic').src = event.target.src; // change the profile pic src
});
```

```css
img {
 height: 150px; 
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.mightyplace.com/Images/Common/profile.jpg" id="profile_pic"/><!-- Your profile pic -->
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/770394499/female_400x400.png" id="unlock_pic"/><!-- Your other pic-->
```